# 24vac transformer inside furnace

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, transformer

I'm adding a humidifier to my furnace. The included 24vac transformer fits nicely on the inner electrical box in the upper furnace compartment.  I like that it keeps everything behind the external switch, and keeps the 24v terminals covered.  However, i wonder if it might get too hot in there.

Is the inner furnace power box a safe location for a transformer?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It should be fine - there are undoubtedly other, similar components related to the furnace itself that are also located inside the cabinet. Just make sure it's securely fastened so that vibrations don't knock it loose.

Sidenote: if it were me, I would replace that smallish beige wirenut with one of those deeper yellow ones so the wires aren't exposed.

Comment: I did not look at the entire photo and missed the wirenut. That size is not rated for 3 conductors, a yellow would be fine or a full sized tan but not that little “fixture” wire nut.

Comment: And there's a pigtail for no reason other than they didn't have a red one.

Answer (score 2):

Putting them in the access panel with other electrical is how I do it all the time. With your primary connections in the box it is safer than many DIY hack jobs I have seen in the past.